# How to make a cloned Windows drive bootable from new location

Tags: windows

I recently installed a larger HDD in my PC which is now the D: drive. My existing HDD where Windows is installed is the C: drive. I've created a new partition on the larger HDD (E:) and successfully cloned C: to E: however I'm struggling to figure out how to make this bootable.

I have a Gigabyte motherboard, and in the BIOS settings I've set the boot order to point to the new drive, however that is not sufficient.

I've seen some tips online that state that in Disk Management I need to make the new partition "active" -- this option is greyed out, and when using DISKPART to accomplish the same task, it states that this is because it is not an MBR volume.

The only tips I've found on how to convert this to an MBR volume point me to using the repair utility in Windows 7 -- when I access this and attempt to run the boot recovery, I get a message stating that

> This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the
> version of windows you are trying to repair. Try using a recovery disc
> that is compatible with this version of windows.

I do not have the Windows 7 installation disc, and I don't know if the MBR business is even necessary, just stating the steps I've taken. Ultimately what I'd like to do is boot Windows from the new E: partition on the new HDD. Any advice for where to begin?

The whole reason I'm doing this is so that I can upgrade my machine to windows 10. But the disk on which Win7 currently resides is too small. So step 1 was to move to the larger HDD and then upgrade there.

[image: Screenshot of Disk Management]

Answer (score 1):

Your new disk was formatted in GPT format, because MBR does not
support disks of more than 2 TB, while yours is 5 TB.

Windows 7 supports GPT partitioned disks, but only for data.
Booting is only supported for 64-bit editions on UEFI-based systems.

However, your computer is too old to use UEFI and instead uses BIOS.
Therefore, you cannot boot from your new disk.

You could probably replace the 5 TB disk by a smaller 2 TB disk and
format it as MBR. You would then be able to clone your entire Disk1
to the new DISK0 (don't copy partitions) using a disk-cloning product.

Comment: I bought a 2TB drive and added it -- it was successfully formatted as MBR which allowed me to mark the drive as "active". I cloned my windows drive (both volumes, the 100MB "System Reserve" volume as well as the main 25GB volume). After updating my BIOS boot order, I get "BOOTMGR is missing" -- I no longer have the windows installation disk -- any pointers on how to get this new cloned drive bootable?

Comment: Which disk-cloning product have you used and how did you clone with it?